# Caveat on $timeout and $interval in AngularJS (1.x)

Tags: angularjs, timeout, setinterval, intervals, angularjs-service

AngularJS provides a convenient way to use setTimeout and setInternal by introducing wrapper services such as [**$timeout**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) and [**$interval**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). I've worked with AngularJS (1.x) for many years and it seems to me that people have just **set-it** and **forget-it** type of function. However, forgetting about cleaning up your timers can cause some serious negative consequences, all the way from code that fails silently to overload your http requests by making repeated requests.

I'm curious on what type of serious side effects can be introduced by abusing $timeout & $interval usages without cleaning up?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main serious side effects that loose timers create. One is specific to AngularJS and one is a general side-effect of any "forgotten" timer in any sort of an application (particularly a GC'ed one).

### Memory leaks

This is a common side-effect of forgotten timers across all GC'ed languages. If you forget a timer and you *think* you destroyed the scope around it (i.e. un-referenced the object), it is still kept around, if it's retained in the timer. For example:

```
const anObject = {
  fn: () => {
    console.log("I'm alive")
  }
};

setInterval(anObject.fn, 1000)

anObject.fn = null;
```

Even though it looks like the function was removed (and we have no access to it anymore as well), it will still be retained in the heap, as it is still referenced internally in `setInterval`.

### Excessive `$digest` cycles

AngularJS's timers have a special behavior that regular timers don't have - they invoke `$digest` cycle. Usually that's a good thing, as otherwise if you make changes inside of the timer, you'd not see data update "propagate" in controllers & templates.

However, `$digest` cycles are expensive, especially in larger applications. And thus having a frequent timer, that's not destroyed when it should be, causes the app to process watchers more often than it needs to. That leads to slow-performing angular views and makes the app laggy.